# How to change the language of the Code Analysis help in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings, code-analysis

I have a small issue with the Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2010. I'm running an English version of Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010 Premium (English version) and Code Analysis. The region, location, number format etc in Windows 7 are set to Switzerland (German).

If I use Code Analysis the messages are displayed in English. If I want to see the description of the rule the Visual Studio is displaying the German version of the MSDN online entry.

How can I change the setting so that Visual Studio displays the English description instead?

Thank you very much!

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact opposite problem: The code analysis help was displayed in German on my computer and because I didn't like the German translation, I wanted it to switch to English. :-)

But the method is the same. Visual Studio uses the Internet Explorer engine to display the help (which is basically only a web page). So you need to change the language preference in your IE settings: *Tools* -> *Internet Options* -> *Languages* button; in the appearing Language Preference dialog, move the desired language (German in your case) to the top.